# Convert xml to atom feed

Tags: php, xml, feed, atom-feed

I would like to convert the xml below to an atom feed:

```
<item>
    <offerStartDate>2012-15-02</offerStartDate>
    <offerEndDate>2012-19-02</offerEndDate>
    <title>Item Title</title> 
    <rrp>14.99</rrp>
    <offerPrice>9.99</offerPrice>
</item>
```

I am able to get the standard atom elements like `<title>` but cannot seem to be able to extend the feed to include foreign elements like `<rrp>`, `<offerPrice>` and so on.

Here's my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>Item sales feed</title>
  <entry>
    <title>Item Title</title> 
    <rrp>14.99</rrp>
    <offerPrice>9.99</offerPrice>
    <image>http://mydomain.com/test/sampleImg.jpg</image>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Somebody please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare elements that aren't defined in the Atom specification you will need to create your own namespace to define the elements.

See there instructions: http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/howto/declare_namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no joy... I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I don't know of another way. The feed will never validate unless you define the nodes.

Comment: You are right about defining the nodes. I just don't know how... I'm new with feeds. A sample code will be of massive help. Thanks

Comment: the link seems to be about RSS, not Atom..(?)